# Why does refs increase 2 for every new object in Python?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

It is a little weird to me that the refs number in the interactive environment increases 2 after a new object is defined. I created only one object, isn't it?

```
>>> v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'v' is not defined
[41830 refs]
>>> v = "v"
[41832 refs]
```

Comment: How are you printing the `refs`?

Comment: -1: At least until you explain *why* you think the reference number is increasing by 2!

Comment: @ScottGriffiths: Isn't that obvious?  41832 - 41830 is 2.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths: That's a good question (and already asked by Tim), but a different question from the one in your last comment.

Comment: That's a debug build of Python.  Call `configure` with the `--with-pydebug` option when building Python, or install the `python-dbg` package on Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: @Seven Marnach, yes, I used debug build of Python. It seems refs is output in debug build automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assignment worked by creating an entry in the `globals()` dictionary that has `v` as a key and `"v"` as a value. That's two references (one for the key and one for the value) although in this case they probably both refer to the same string `"v"`.